# RESTService returns HTML when writer does not contain data

Tags: java, xpages

I'm currently developing RESservices using the customService bean. One thing I've noticed is that for some reason when I dont use the responsewriter object but only set the response status using engine.getHttpResponse().setStatus(404) (for instance). The header is correctly set ( 404 ) but there is still some html generated.

I've already tried to set the rendered property on the view tag (of the xpage) to false but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Is there some documentation on how to use the CustomServiceBean and not returning any data?

Comment: What is the HTML generated? Can you show the code (XPage)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the Status is a good approach, so the API is easy to handle. However you want to consider:

- set the content type to what would actually be rendered if you had a result. If you don't set response.contenttype it defaults to HTML
- 404 is meant for navigation/urls. Since your XPage renders a result, the request found a valid URL. That based on user and/or parameters there's no result isn't therefore a 4xx class of error, but rather a 5xx. Pick one of them.
- when testing use wget or curl, so you can be sure the browser doesn't do the HTML

Let us know how it goes

Comment: Setting the content type was indeed the correct answer. What I did was to create a class which is responsible for the output format. So when the client is requesting json I invoke a different 'outputhandler'. if noe content type is requested json will be default. 

After adding the content-type header my problem was solved but occasionally chrome still thinks its HTML. For now I assume that's a bug in Chrome since Restclient is receiving plain data and its 100% json.

Answer (score 1):

I think returning a 404 response causes always HTML data as it normally gives you the error message etc.
If you don't want to response with any data just return an empty JSON object - as I assume you return JSON when you HAVE data, right?

Comment: mmm that somehow does not feel right.. When the service returns 404 it means that what was to be found could not be found. Returning an empty json object could lead the client to think there is still something to parse which in fact isn't the case. 

I've already played a bit around with the httpservletresponse object and it seems that when using the restclient project ( http://xpag.es/?1CCA) there is in fact no response created but the browser just adds default html to it when the response headers have not been set.

Comment: so maybe that's a browser-side "problem". Thinking of that stupid "friendly error messages" in IE *grml*

Comment: Ah ok, now I know what you mean: the service gives an empty response that causes the browser to interpret this as HTML. So you might pass this issue to @pdhannan

Answer (score 1):

dont set 404 status ,set null for this case,ant error status like 404 means creating html for that

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @mah - actually, this **is** an answer.  If you wish to dispute its *accuracy* then do so - but please do not post form comments which suggest you have not actually read the question and answer you are commenting on.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I didn't post the comment manually and was not even aware of it having been done - must be the result of a review action taken. If I'm wrong about the post being an answer, so be it (this is why actions take votes; we're all capable of getting it wrong).